# Time ordered integral involving beta function:

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, specific-calculation, iterated-integral

> Any help on unpacking integrals of the following type, would be
>   helpful: $$ \int_0^1 \int_0^r  r^a (1-r)^b  t^n (1-t)^m dr  dt $$  where $a, b, n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0  \le t \le 1$.

Edit/Update (2/9/19)

**Some background:**  For the case ``$n=1$'', here is how the solution and proof goes...
Label the integral $\beta_1(n,m):= \int_0^1 t^n (1-t)^m dt$.  Then we first note that $\beta_1(n,0) = \frac{1}{n+1}$.  Next we consider the expression,
$$R: = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \left( t^n (1-t)^m \right) dt.$$
On the one hand, the fundamental theorem of calculus yields
$$R = t^n (1-t)^m \Big\vert_0^1 = 0.$$
On the other hand, by using the product rule we get, 
$$R = n \beta_1(n-1,m) - m \beta_1(n, m-1).$$
Together we see that we can write, 
$$\beta_1(n,m) = \frac{m}{m+1}\beta_1(n+1, m-1).$$
Finally we put together our relations on $\beta_1(n,m)$ with our initial condition, $\beta_1(n,m) = \frac{1}{n+1}$, to obtain
$$\beta_1(n,m) = \frac{n! m!}{(n+m + 1)!}$$

Comment: what is the meaning of the $>$ sign inside the integrand? and what is the meaning of $0>\leq s$ ?

Comment: Sorry those symbols accidentally snuck in during my last edit where I added the yellow box formatting

Answer (score 1):

I presume with "the case $n=2$" you mean the integral
$$\beta_2(n,m,p,q)=\int _0^1\int _0^t(1-t)^m t^n s^p (1-s)^qdsdt=\frac{m!(n+p+1)!}{(p+1) (m+n+p+2)!}\,\, _3F_2(p+1,n+p+2,-q;p+2,m+n+p+3;1)$$
which might well be further simplified, at least in special cases. For example,
$$\beta_2(1,m,p,q)=\frac{[(m+1)!(p+1)!+q]  p! (m+q+1)!}{(m+1) (m+2) (m+p+q+3)!},$$
$$\beta_2(n,1,p,q)=\frac{q!}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left(\frac{p!}{(p+q+1)!}-\frac{(n q+2n+p+2 q+4) (n+p+1)!}{(n+p+q+3)!}\right),$$
$$\beta_2(n,m,p,1)=\frac{m (m-1)! (mp+2m+n+2 p+4) (n+p+1)!}{\left(p^2+3 p+2\right) (m+n+p+3)!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  You understood n=2 precisely, despite the abuse of letters.  Is there a reference or an argument for how to simplify these in general?